# get value from .xml to .java parse(float = null) error

Tags: android

**file.xml**

```
edittext(inputtype=numberdecimal, id=text1) value(1.5)
edittext(inputtype=numberdecimal, id=text2) value("")
```

**file.java**

```
txt1 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.Text1));
txt2 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.Text2));

s1 = txt1.getText().toString(); 
v1 = Float.parseFloat(s1);     //true
s2 = txt2.getText().toString(); 
v2 = Float.parseFloat(s2);     //error i want parse to (0)
```

Why is Error?
if text not input data i want default value to zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`""` is not a valid number, so you are most likely getting a `NumberFormatException` as said in the Android [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat%28java.lang.String%29). Easiest thing to do is `catch` that `NumberFormatException`  and set your text there. Repeat as needed.

Eg

```
try {
  v2 = Float.parseFloat(s2);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
  v2 = 0;
}
```